# How to assign a name to an output global dataframe in a function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have about 12 datasets that I am trying to clean before implementing them as datatables in my final code. I currently have code that works for individual datasets but I want to implement this as a function so that I don't have to re-type the code blocks over and over.

```
countyshapesClean <- function(inputdata, outputdata) {
  outputdata <<- inputdata %>%
select(
  county_cl,
  state_abb,
  avg_opioid,
  avg_oxy_hydro,
  avg_opioid_perc,
  avg_oxy_hydro_perc,
  avg_opioid_ppp,
  avg_oxy_hydro_ppp
) %>% 
mutate(
  avg_opioid = format(round(as.numeric(avg_opioid),2), nsmall = 2, big.mark = ","),
  avg_oxy_hydro = format(round(as.numeric(avg_oxy_hydro),2), nsmall = 2, big.mark = ","),
  avg_opioid_perc = format(round(as.numeric(avg_opioid_perc),2), nsmall = 2, big.mark = ","),
  avg_oxy_hydro_perc = format(round(as.numeric(avg_oxy_hydro_perc),2), nsmall = 2, big.mark = ","),
  avg_opioid_ppp = format(round(as.numeric(avg_opioid_ppp),2), nsmall = 2, big.mark = ","),
  avg_oxy_hydro_ppp = format(round(as.numeric(avg_oxy_hydro_ppp),2), nsmall = 2, big.mark = ",")
)
}

countyshapesClean(inputdata = countymerge2006, outputdata = countymerge2006clean)
```

This works but my output dataset is named `outputdata` instead of `countymerge2006clean`. How would I change this code to get my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass in `outputdata` to the function. Instead, do something like

```
countymerge2006clean <- countyshapesClean(inputdata = countymerge2006)
```

where your function returns the updated data.frame.

```
countyshapesClean <- function(inputdata) {
  inputdata %>%
  select(...) %>% 
  mutate(...)
}
```

Proper functions in R should not create variables outside their own scope. (It's not considered good practice to use `<<-`).

Of course, almost anything is possible is R, and you could create variables outside the function scope with the `assign()` function (though I strongly recommend you do NOT do this). That would look something like this

```
countyshapesClean <- function(inputdata, outputdata) {
  outvar <- rlang::ensym(outputdata)
  new <- inputdata %>%
    select(...) %>% 
    mutate(...)
  assign(rlang::quo_name(outvar), new, parent.frame())
}
countyshapesClean(inputdata = countymerge2006, outputdata = countymerge2006clean)
```

Comment: This could work! But I need the output dataset to be a different name

Comment: @AnirudhNambiar This does give it a different name. You just assign to whatever variable name you want. Above the new variable `countymerge2006clean` is created.

Comment: Ohhh I'm an idiot! Thanks so much! I'll accept this as an answer.